# CodeIgniter Cache feels unfinished

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I've been experimenting with CodeIgniters cache and I read the following:

> Cache files DO NOT expire. Any queries that have been cached will
>   remain cached until you delete them. The caching system permits you
>   clear caches associated with individual pages, or you can delete the
>   entire collection of cache files. Typically you’ll want to use the
>   housekeeping functions described below to delete cache files after
>   certain events take place, like when you’ve added new information to
>   your database.

I find this behavior kind of strange, since most of us use CI's query builder, why doesn't it just store cache files on a per table basis rather than a per controller basis and just delete cache files on `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` when performed on that table via query builder? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**
After some experimentation I came up with this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171705/codeigniter-cache-replacement

Comment: Huh? This doesn't seem to be related.